# c# defining own property types with parameters

Tags: c#

I have a domain class where I'm not allowed to change the types of any of the objects (domain is too currently too complex and tightly bound). I can however add extra mapping properties if needed.

The domain class below has two properties which are non-nullable bools. I need to have be able to assign null values to these two properties.

```
public class POCMainClassOriginal
{
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
    public bool MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the simple solution of adding a mapping property:

```
public class POCMainClassModified
{
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
    public bool? MappedMyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return MyProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            MyProperty = value.HasValue ? value.Value : false;
        }
    }

    public bool MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public bool? MappedMyProperty2
    {
        get
        {
            return MyProperty2;
        }
        set
        {
            MyProperty2 = value.HasValue ? value.Value : false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now adding the extra 10 lines of code on every mapped property seems extensive and repetitive. Is there a neat and clear way of defining a possibly extension method or new class to allow me to simplify those extensions.

```
public class POCExtensions
{
    public bool? POCBool
    {
        get
        {
            return OriginalValue;
        }
        set
        {
            OriginalValue = value.HasValue ? value.Value : false;
        }
    }
}

public class POCMainClassModifiedAgain
{
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
    public POCExtensions.POCBool MappedMyProperty { get; set; }

    public bool MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public POCExtensions.POCBool MappedMyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the classes above I would also need to somehow pass the original value through.

NB: While I'm aware there might be simpler ways of solving the bool problem I'm interested in how to simplify the property definition.

Comment: Note that even when you assign `null`, you'll still read `false` - is that what you intended?

Comment: Is there any reason you need the non-nullable properties? Just have the nullable ones, and use `Foo ?? false` where you need to convert to a non-nullable representation...

Comment: I mean my first question is, this all seems a bit pointless. If a null is false, why does it need to be nullable?

Comment: I didn't really want to bring this into the conversation, this will be due to a move to EF with a domain having non-nullables and the DB allowing nulls. The move is from nhibernate which allowed this but EF does not. But my original question still stands on how to simplify the property.